# Losing rep for selecting another answer?

Tags: support, reputation, accepted-answer, community-wiki

I just unaccepted an old answer and reselected a community wiki answer on an old question of mine:

[Do you use Javadoc for every method you write?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211041/do-you-use-javadoc-for-every-method-you-write)

I appear to have lost 2 rep points for this action. Why is that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Normally, when you accept an answer, you are given 2 reputation points.

However, that does not apply when you accept an answer you posted yourself, *or* if the answer is a community wiki answer. The answer you have now accepted, is a community wiki (CW) post.

So when you switched your accepted answer flag to that one, you lost the 2 points for having accepted the other answer, and did not gain them again for accepting the CW answer.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: I didn't know that. Why do you not get rep for accepting an answer if it is CW?

Comment: @Asad: Presumably for the same reasons you don't get rep for upvotes on CW posts, nor loose rep for downvotes. The original author of the post doesn't receive the 15 rep acceptance bonus either, so not giving the +2 to the question poster is symmetrical to that.

Answer (score 1):

Accepting the old answer gave you +2 points. Unaccepting took them away again.

You don't gain those points for accepting a CW answer, so you didn't get +2 again.

Comment: It wasn't his own answer he selected, it was someone else's community wiki answer.

Comment: Oh, in that case, it's the answer being CW that doesn't earn you the rep back.